# ng-repeat not rendering data from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on a web app where non-profit organizations can create a profile and be easily searchable by various parameters. In the "create and organization" form, I have a nested array where the organization can add donations that they need. The array is storing ok (I can add multiple donations), however when I try to display it using ng-repeat, nothing renders. When I don't use the ng-repeat and just display via {{ ctrl.organization.donations }} the information shows up with brackets and quotation marks.

Here is the code that I use to add the donations (via the newOrganization controller):

```
    function NewOrganizationController(OrganizationService, CategoryService, $stateParams, $state, $http, Auth){

    var ctrl = this;

  CategoryService.getCategories().then(function(resp) {
    ctrl.categories = resp.data;
  });

  ctrl.donations = [{text: ''}];

  Auth.currentUser().then(function(user) {
    ctrl.user = user;
  })

  ctrl.addNewDonation = function() {
    var newDonation = ctrl.donations.length+1;
    ctrl.donations.push({text: ''});
  };

  ctrl.removeDonation = function() {
      var lastItem = ctrl.donations.length-1;
      ctrl.donations.splice(lastItem);
    };

  ctrl.addOrganization = function() {
    var donations = this.donations;
    var allDonations = [];

    for (var key in donations) {
      if (donations.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var donation = donations[key].text;
        allDonations.push(donation);
      }
    }
    var data = {
        name: ctrl.organization.name,
        description: ctrl.organization.description,
        address: ctrl.organization.address,
        donations: allDonations.join("/r/n"),
        category_id: this.category.id
    };


    OrganizationService.createOrganization(data);
    $state.go('home.organizations');
  };

}


angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('NewOrganizationController', NewOrganizationController);
```

Here is the code that I am using to display the array on my show page (this is what shows up with brackets, i.e. donations needed: ["food", "clothing"]):

```
<h5>{{ ctrl.organization.donations }}</h5>
```

This is the ng-repeat code that is not rendering anything to the page:

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="donation in donations track by $index">
   {{ donation }}
 </li>
```

I've tried to use .join(', ') within the {{donation}} brackets, but this isn't recognized as a function.

edit: After taking AJ's suggestion here is a screenshot of what appears...anyone know how to fix this?

[seems that my array is showing up in table form, with each row containing one character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5q9NW.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is a [link](https://github.com/mirandalily/raven/tree/Development) to the github repo in case you want to look at anything else or get a bigger picture.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same variable name that works in the `h5`

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="donation in ctrl.organization.donations track by $index">
   {{ donation }}
</li>
```

Comment: AJ - thanks for the answer! Something does appear when I do that, but it's coming out in table form, and each row has one character in it.

Comment: This is a list item, why would you expect it to be in table form? You will have to provide more of your HTML/CSS if you want help with that

Comment: I'm not expecting it to be in table form. I added a screenshot in my original post of what ctrl.organization.donations track by $index does. Maybe table isn't the right word, but I've never seen the issue I've run into before.

Comment: It looks like `ctrl.organization.donations` is a string instead of an array